# React Native - How to delete a list using filter

Tags: react-native, filter, mapping

I have been trying to delete a list when pressing the button, but it does not work at all. I know I should use `value.id !== id`, so I did, but pretty not so sure if the way I tried is correct.

Here is the code I tried.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const cartData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    store: 'Zaful',
    productImage:
      'https://gloimg.zafcdn.com/zaful/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/01/20/thumb-img/1612378696788831740.jpg',
    productName: 'Jacket',
    optColor: 'black',
    optSize: 'S',
    price: 50000,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    store: 'Zaful',
    productImage:
      'https://gloimg.zafcdn.com/zaful/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2020/09/28/goods-img/1603157669032643775.jpg',
    productName: 'Padded Jacket',
    optColor: 'Blue',
    optSize: 'S',
    price: 35000,
  },
];

const PaymentCart = ({ selectedNum, totalNum }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [cart, setCart] = useState(cartData);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([]);
  const isAllChecked = isChecked.length === cartData.length;
  const setIsAllChecked = () => {
    setIsChecked(isAllChecked ? [] : [...cartData.map((item) => item.id)]);
  };

  const handleChecked = (id) => {
   
    setIsChecked((prevState) => {
      const index = prevState.indexOf(id); 
      if (index === -1) {
        return [...prevState, id];
      } else {
        const tempArr = [...prevState];
        tempArr.splice(index, 1);
        return [...tempArr];
      }
    });
  };

  // This is the function I want to fix
  const onRemove = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    const newCart = cart.filter((value) => value.id !== id);
    setCart(newCart);
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      {cartData?.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <ScrollView>
            <CheckBoxSet
              isChecked={isAllChecked}
              setIsChecked={setIsAllChecked}
              checkBoxText={'Select All (2/3)'}
              deletedText={'Delete Selected'}
            />
            <View style={[styles.contentBox]}>
              <Text style={[styles.storeName]}>{cartData[0].store}</Text>
              {cartData.map((item, index) => (
                <View key={item.id} style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>
                  <CheckBoxSet
                    isChecked={isChecked.includes(item.id)}
                    setIsChecked={() => handleChecked(item.id)}
                    checkBoxText={'Select'}
                    deletedText={'Delete'}
                    checkBoxTextStyle={[styles.checkBoxText]}
                    containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 13 }}

                    // This is what I want to fix
                    deleteOnPress={() => onRemove(item.id)}
                  />
                  <ProductInfoBox
                    price={item.price}
                    productImage={{
                      uri: item.productImage,
                    }}
                    productName={item.productName}
                    optColor={item.optColor}
                    optSize={item.optSize}
                  />
                </View>
              ))}
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </>
      ) : (
        <View style={[styles.noProductsContainer]}>
          <Text style={[styles.noProducts]}>장바구니에 상품이 없어요.</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default PaymentCart;
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong. Perhaps is it related to `setIsAllChecked`? Should I use that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map on `cart` not `cartData`:

because  `onRemove` modifies `cart`

```
 {cart.map((item, index) => (
```

Comment: That does really work, and now I am trying to delete all selected items, but there I cannot use `id` since the component which has the props, `deletedText={'Delete Selected'}`, is not being mapped. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: sorry it's not clear for me what you want to do, can you give more explanation if possible.

Comment: @Mohammad Now I would like to delete all items, but `delete all` button is not being mapped, so I have no idea how to let the button delete all items.. Does it make sense?

Comment: if you `setCart([])`  doesn't to the job?

Comment: @Mohammad sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you set cart to an empty array